# Webpack and changing branches in git - never-ending conflicts

Tags: git, webpack, gulp, diff, merge-conflict-resolution

I'm using Webpack for compiling all my front-end assets but I guess the same question is valid for gulp or grunt.

I have tons of .scss files that I merge into min.css files. The problem is, if I have x developers working on y branches - every time I try to merge a branch I'm getting conflicts because the min.css files are conflicting.

It's easy to resolve (actually it happens automatically as Webpack is just overwriting these files once I checkout) but with tons of merging daily it is frustrating (all the waiting for Webpack to run). I'm wondering what's the ideal work flow here? I've been using Rails assets pipeline before and it was magnificent I didn't even know when the assets were compiled.

Maybe I should add the min.css files to gitignore and re-create them on the server? But how about folks who are back-ends and don't want/have web pack installed / don't know how to run it?

My projects use PHP mainly.

Answer (score 3):

Ignore your compiled assets using .gitignore.

Build them each time when they are being pulled.

Comment: How to build them only when they're being pulled?

Comment: `git pull` -> `npm install` -> `npm run build/prod`

Answer (score 2):

There are very few reasons to add generated files to source control. In this case, you should `git rm *.min.css` and add a line to `.gitignore` with `*.min.css` (or better yet the folder that contains your generated files).

Comment: How to do that? If I ignore them then I won't push them to my dev / production servers.

Comment: @Wordpressor When you create a release, you should build directly from the source and then copy the generated files to your servers. Pushing from the source controlled files won't guarantee that the generated files are built correctly. If you use CI, then the CI server can run any appropriate build scripts.